# How to pull data from the database-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, numbers

```
class LeavesController extends Controller
    {
    public function pullCon()

    {
        return json_encode(Leaves::all());
    }

    }

    this is my route



    Route::get('/folder/leaves', 'LeavesController@pullMetod');






    and this is my json why wont it work


     $(document).ready(function(){

     $.ajax({

            url:"/folder/leaves",

            type: "get",

            success: function(resuLt)
            {

                consoLe.log(result);
                let obj = JSON.parse(result);
                consoLe.log(obj);
                $("table").append(<tr> <td>ID</td> <td>Name</td> <td>Mass</td> 
       <td>Year</td> </tr>);
                for( let i=0; i<obj.lenght; i++)
                {
                    $("table").append('<tr>');
                    $("table").append('<td>' + obj[i].id + '</td>');
                    $("table").append('<td>' + obj[i].earth_mass + '</td>');
                    $("table").append('<td>' + obj[i].year_lenght + '</td>');
                    $("table").append('</tr>');
                }
            }

        });

        });
```

It requires doctrine/dbal as a dependency. But some migration features already need DBAL to work. Make sure you fill out table_catalog (which I guess is equatable to database). You may have to tweak your results a bit.

Comment: In ajax({}}) you using dataType:'json',

Answer (score 0):

```
class SongController extends Controller
{
 public function dovuci()
 {
    $PParniValjak = Song::where("band_name","=","ParniValjak")
    ->where("length",">",300)
    ->get();

    foreach($PParniValjak as $pesma)
    {
        $pesma->lenght /= 60;
    }

    return view ('pesme_podaci')->with('ParniValjak',$PParniValjak);
 }
 public function obrisi()
 {
    $PParniValjak = Song::where("band_name","=","Parni valjak")
    ->where("id","asc")
    ->get();

    $PParniValjak = $PParniValjak->splice(1);
    foreach($PParniValjak as $pesma)
    {
        print_r(pesma);
        $pesma->delete();
       }
    }
}
```

i think this is your Scontroler

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



</head>
<body>
<table>
    tr
        th Band Name:/th           
        th Song Name: /th
        th >Band lenght:/th
    /tr
        @foreach(@CrvenaJabuka as $pesme)
            tr
                td{{$pesma->band_name}}/td
                td{{$pesma->song_name}}/td
                td{{$number_format($pesma->lenght,2)->band_name}}/td
            /tr
        @endforeach
 </table>
```

and this is your songs-data